# Error while updating property of a view managed by: RNSVGPPath

Tags: react-native

There is an error in 1 line of my code, but I don't know how to solve it. Please help me, I'm just a beginner.

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.root}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Svg {...{width,height}}>
        <Path d={line} fill="transparent" stroke="#367BE2" strokeWidth={5} />
        <Path d={'${line} L ${width} ${height} L 0 ${height}'} fill="red"/>
      </Svg>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
```

The error is on this line:

Path d={'${line} L ${width} ${height} L 0 ${height}'} fill="red"

I expect that there will be red background in the graph as the output, but it result in an error

[CLick Here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68ysk.jpg)

Comment: width and height have null values. did you intend to use props on svg component?
can you tell, where do you get ...{width,height}?

Comment: const height = 200;
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const verticalPadding = 5;
const cursorRadius = 10;
const labelWidth = 100;

Comment: i think your error here is using single quote on this line <Path d={'${line} L ${width} ${height} L 0 ${height}'} fill="red"/> try to modify the string using backtick ` ` instead of single quote ' '

Comment: wow yes, thank you very much!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer here. then marked it as the correct answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your error here is using single quote on this line

```
<Path d={'${line} L ${width} ${height} L 0 ${height}'} fill="red"/>
```

try to modify the string using backtick `` instead of single quote ' '